# Golang Parameters conversion

Tags: go, struct, interface

Can somebody explain how can this happened?

I put `interface` as parameter in a function. While invoking this function I pass `struct` into it, but it didn't give me error. Here's the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/myusername/gomodel/domain"
    "github.com/myusername/gomodel/model"
)

func main() {
    db := model.InitDB()

    newFunc(db)
}


func newFunc(db domain.IUser) {

    r, err := db.CreateUserTable()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

I've implemented the interface somewhere else in the code, because the program just work as the implemented interface expected to be.
`IUser` is an interface whose member is:

```
type IUser interface {
    CreateUserTable() (sql.Result, error)
}
```

`InitDB` is a function to open the database and return struct of database:

```
type DB struct {
    *sql.DB
}

//InitDB initializes the database
func InitDB() *DB {
    db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to initialize database: ",err)
    }
    err2 := db.Ping()
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }

    return &DB{db}
}
```

My question is: how can a function with a parameter type interface be passed a different type of parameter? And how is this working under the hood?

Comment: If the the `*DB` type implements the method `CreateUserTable() (sql.Result, error)` then it implicitly implements the interface and can be used anywhere where that interface is expected.

Comment: ... see here: https://play.golang.org/p/LMI8pcu2gAX, you'll notice that the compiler complains in the second case but not in the first. In Go interfaces are implemented implicitly, that means you don't need to explicitly state that a type implements an interface, the type just needs to implement the method set of the interface and it can be used in its place automatically.

Comment: That's the point of interfaces. Concrete values are never values *of* the interface type, they're values of some other type that satisfies the interface, and that allows them to be assigned to variables / passed to parameters of the interface type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Golang Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)

> An interface type specifies a method set called its interface. A
>   variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method
>   set that is any superset of the interface. Such a type is said to
>   implement the interface.

This is because interface can be implemented as a wrapper to every type. Interface actually points to two things mainly one is the underlying type which is a struct here and other one is the value of that type which is a pointer to DB

You see `newFunc` is actually taking `interface{}` as an argument, So you can pass anything to it of type `T` which can be of primitive types too.

```
func main() {
    db := model.InitDB()

    newFunc(db)
}
```

So In case you want to get the underlying value you need to type assert. Interface works like a wrapper to the struct here and save its type and value which can be get using type assertion.